# Parse and format message/http on Windows Phone

Tags: .net, http, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I need to format and parse content of MIME type `message/http` [as specified in RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-19.1). To be more specific, I need to format a HTTP/1.1 request and parse a HTTP/1.1 response, but without actually do any network communication. Target platform is Windows Phone 8.

In Java I use Apache HttpCore library. Is there something similar in .NET that I can use in a Windows Phone app? Or maybe there is some other smart way that doesn't include implement the format from scratch?

Comment: Actually, RFC 7230. See http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7230.html#internet.media.type.message.http

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in parser per-se that you could leverage that is available through the exposed .NET APIs in Windows Phone. You could write your own parser or rely on such classes as `HttpWebResponse` and `HttpWebRequest` to have an abstracted-out model of the message.